# file input from the user

Tags: java, file, file-io

I was trying to take the input of the filename from the user and then proceed to doing all the calculations. but it keeps returning me an error. the file exists in the same directory.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class test{
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
//File fin = new File ("matrix1.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.nextLine(); // removes the first line in the input file 
String rowLine = scanner.nextLine();
String[] arr = rowLine.split("=");
int rows = Integer.parseInt(arr[1].trim());

String colLine = scanner.nextLine();
String[] arr2 = colLine.split("=");
int cols = Integer.parseInt(arr2[1].trim());
double [][]matrix = new double [rows][cols];

 for (int i=0; i<rows;i++){
     for (int j=0; j<cols;j++) {
         matrix[i][j]= scanner.nextDouble();
        } 
}


System.out.println(rows);
System.out.println(cols);  

 for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) 
  { for (int j=0;j<cols;j++) {
    System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
 }   
}
```

}
    }

Comment: <"main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at test.main(test.java:12)>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one issue with the code. The scanner will just give you the name of the file as string from command line. So, you need to first get the command line argument and then create one more scanner using the constructor which takes file object. e.g.

```
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(scanner.nextLine()));
    String rowLine = fileScanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(rowLine);
    String[] arr = rowLine.split("=");
    int rows = Integer.parseInt(arr[1].trim())
```

Answer (score 0):

You realize that you are only using a Scanner of type System.in, right? This means that you aren't even looking at a file, you are looking at user input only. This is regardless of whether you have the first line commented out or not. To use a file, you could use a FileInputStream or a couple other File handling classes.

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(new File("matrix1.txt"));
//do stuff with the stream
```

Heres the java docs for FileInputStream: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

Edit: After seeing your comment on what the actual error was, I realize there are more problems with the code than just the way you are handling input. Your error is almost certainly happening at one of the first 2 array accessors, the arr[1](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html).trim() calls. That means the user input has nothing on the right side of the "=" sign, or there is no "=" sign in the user input.

Comment: thanks for the help. i don't think there was an issue with the trim() calls as my input file has the "=" sign.